# Induced inner product on tensor powers.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

Let $V$ be a real or complex inner product space with inner product $\left\langle \cdotp,\cdotp\right\rangle$. For $\otimes ^kV$ define $\left\langle \cdotp,\cdotp\right\rangle_k$ by 
$$\left\langle u_1\otimes ...\otimes u_k,v_1\otimes ...\otimes v_k\right\rangle_k = \left\langle u_1,v_1\right\rangle...\left\langle u_k,v_k\right\rangle$$
on pure tensors, and extend bilinearly.

Is the resulting object $\left\langle \cdotp,\cdotp\right\rangle_k$ an inner product on $\otimes ^kV$? It is clearly a symmetric bilinear form. Is it non-degenerate and positive definite though?

Comment: do $v_i=u_i$ for all the $i$ and infer

Comment: That only gives the result for tensors of the particular form above.

Comment: you need to do that in order to check your last question